# How to get the app root path in play2?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In play1, we can get the app path by:

```
Play.applicationPath
```

How to do the same in Play2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Scala API, you can do it like this to get a `java.io.File` to the app:

```scala
import play.api.Play.current
Play.application.path
```

In Java:

```java
import play.Play;
Play.application().path();
```

Comment: for those wondering, using Java it's File root=Play.application().path();

Comment: I get a "cannot find symbol" if I try to use Play.application().path() in Java. What do you import?

Comment: In scala play 2.2, use the same import with current.path instead

Answer (score 2):

For Play 2.5.x it should be like this. I keep the stuffs not related to the question. However, should be handy for other things.

```
package io

import javax.inject.Inject
import com.google.inject.Singleton
import play.Application
import play.api.Environment

@Singleton
class File @Inject()(environment: Environment, application: Application) {
    val home: java.io.File = application.path()
}
```